# Single language ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, xcode5

I have a project in Xcode 5.0 and I want to support only a specific language different from english, for intance, pt. When the project is created, it has "Use base internationalization" checked. A tried adding my language and removing english, then when I run the app on a device of that language (pt), everything is ok, the controls of a image picker, for instance, are localized. But, if the device's language is english or a different one (for instance fr), the controls are shown in english. How can I force the app to show all controls in my language (pt)?
Maybe it is noob question, but when I uncheck "Use base internationalization" I lose the storyboard, and when I try to check again it asks for files but no options are shown. How can I change the reference language of base internationalization?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. In my opinion Apple has a lot of work to do on this area with XCode.